# Image in the background of drawn canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I tried the following without success:

```
Bitmap mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.chart_bg).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444, true);

canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground, 0, 0, null);
```

But I am getting the image after the canvas is drawn but not in the background of it.

Is there a way to put the image in the background of canvas that is already drawn?

Comment: is the draw method of a custom view then you can set the background of the custom view

Comment: Setting the background of the custom view is giving blank background as if I didn't set it. Its a `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`.